# Start foreach loop on associative array at the second element

Tags: php

I have associative array such as:

```
$myArray = array(
  'key1' => 'val 1',
  'key2' => 'val 2'
  ...
);
```

I do not know the key values up front but want to start looping from the second element.  In the example above, that would be from key2 onwards.

I tried

```
foreach(next(myArray) as $el) {

}
```

but that didnt work.

Alternatives may be `array_slice` but that seems messy.  Am i missing something obvious?

Answer (score 27):

There really is no *"one true way"* of doing this. So I'll take it as a benchmark as to where you should go.

All information is based on this array.

```
$array = array(
    1 => 'First',
    2 => 'Second',
    3 => 'Third',
    4 => 'Fourth',
    5 => 'Fifth'
);
```

---

The [array_slice()](http://php.net/array_slice) option. You said you thought this option was overkill, but it seems to me to be the shortest on code.

```
foreach (array_slice($array, 1) as $key => $val)
{
    echo $key . ' ' . $val . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Doing this 1000 times takes `0.015888` seconds.

---

There is the array functions that handle the pointer, such as ...

- [`current()`](http://php.net/currrent) - Return the current element in an array.
- [`end()`](http://php.net/end) - Set the internal pointer of an array to its last element.
- [`prev()`](http://php.net/prev) - Rewind the internal array pointer.
- [`reset()`](http://php.net/reset) - Set the internal pointer of an array to its first element.
- [`each()`](http://php.net/each) - Return the current key and value pair from an array and advance the array cursor.

**Please note that the `each()` function has been deprecated as of PHP 7.2, and will be removed in PHP 8.**

These functions give you the fastest solution possible, over 1000 iterations.

```
reset($array);
while (next($array) !== FALSE)
{
    echo key($array) . ' ' . current($array) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Doing this 1000 times, takes `0.014807` seconds.

---

Set a variable option.

```
$first = FALSE;
foreach ($array as $key => $val)
{
    if ($first != TRUE)
    {
        $first = TRUE;
        continue;
    }

    echo $key . ' ' . $val . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Doing this 1000 times takes `0.01635` seconds.

---

I rejected the [array_shift](http://php.net/array_shift) options because it edits your array and you've never said that was acceptable.

Comment: I like the array_slice option.  Very clean

Answer (score 5):

This depends on whether you want to do this just once or many times, and on whether you still need the original array later on.

#### "First" pattern

```
$first = true;
foreach ($array as $key=>value) {
    if($first) {
        $first = false;
        continue;
    }
    // ... more code ...
}
```

I personally use this solution quite often because it's really straight-forward, everybody gets this. Also, there is no performance hit of creating a new array and you can still operate on the original array after the loop.

However, if you have a couple of loops like this, it kind of starts looking a little unclean, because you need 5 extra lines of code per loop.

#### array_shift

```
array_shift($array);
foreach ($array as $key=>value) {
    // .... more code ....
}
```

[`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-shift.php) is a function tailored to this special case of not wanting the first element. Essentially it's a Perl-ish way of saying `$array = array_slice($array, 1)` which might not be completely obvious, especially since it modifies the original array.

So, you might want to make a copy of the original array and shift it, if you need both the shifted array multiple times and also the original array later on.

#### array_slice

And, of course, there is `array_slice` itself. I don't see anything wrong with `array_slice` if you want the original array to remain unchanged and you need the sliced array multiple times. However, if you're positive that you always want to slice just one element off, you might as well use the shorthand `array_shift` (and make a copy before if needed).

Comment: I created a duplicate and used `array_shift` 

Answer (score 2):

You can go with the obvious way:

```
$flag = false;
foreach($myArray as $el) {
   if($flag) {
      // do what you want
   }
   $flag = true;
}
```

Comment: i am not completely sold on this.  It will work but it seems like lots of unnecessary checks during a loop.

Comment: you're right but since its a boolean check I am sure that you will never see performance loss

Answer (score 2):

Just another way of flexible iteration:

```
reset($myArray);  // set array pointer to the first element  
next($myArray);   // skip first element

while (key($myArray) !== null) {

  // do something with current($myArray)

  next($myArray);
}
```

As far as I know `foreach` is just a kind of shortcut for this construction.

From Zend PHP 5 Certication study guide:

> As you can see, using this set of functions [reset, next, key,
>   current, ...] requires quite a bit of work; to be fair, there are some
>   situations where they offer the only reasonable way of iterating
>   through an array, particularly if you need to skip back-and-forth
>   between its elements. If, however, all you need to do is iterate
>   through the entire array from start to ﬁnish, PHP provides a handy
>   shortcut in the form of the foreach() construct.

Comment: `<?php

 $array = array(
  'First',
  'Second',
  'Third',
  'Forth',
  'Fifth'
 );

 reset($array);
 while (next($array) !== FALSE)
 {
  echo current($array) . PHP_EOL;
 }

?>`

Comment: @MarkTomlin even better!

Answer (score 2):

If your array was *0 based*, it would be `if($key>=1)`, but as your array starts at *key 1*, then this should work.

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value){if($key>=2){
        do stuff    
        }}
```

Comment: array_slice works without having to know how the key are formatted and works on non-numeric keys. It always removes the first `$offset` elements. As a general rule, it's always better to use a built in function than it is program your way around it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$temp = array_shift($arr);
foreach($arr as $val) {
   // do something
}
array_unshift($arr, $temp);
```

Comment: I think modifying the array just to iterate through it is a bad idea

Comment: @andrewtweber I don't disagree, but it depends on what the reason for skipping the first element is. There are a number of ways to achieve what the OP asked - this is an option that might be appropriate for reasons he hasn't gone into.

Answer (score 1):

```
reset($myArray);  
next($myArray); 

while ($element = each($myArray))
{
    //$element['key'] and $element['value'] can be used
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My fairly simple solution when this issue pops up. It has the nice advantage of being easily being modified to be able to skip more than just the first element if you want it to.

```
$doomcounter = 0;    
foreach ($doomsdayDevice as $timer){ if($doomcounter == 0){$doomcounter++; continue;} 

   // fun code goes here

}
```

Comment: array_slice does the same thing with the second argument and I'll bet it's faster, but I'll leave the benchmarking on that to someone else.